# Angular - Finding and cleaning up services, that are not injected anywhere

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I am working for a company with a big Angular project. Over the years it grew and changed. By now I noticed there are some services, that were forgotten to be cleaned up, when changes were made.

Since the project is big I try to find an automated way to identify such services. I am seeking for a mechanism, that lists me services, that are not injected anywhere in the project.

I tried to google this, but all I get are recommendations for clean code etc. I was hoping for a command, maybe a cool IDE function from WebStorm or VSCode.

Comment: If you use VS Code and you have references on classes enabled, you can simply have VS Code show you all the references. If the only references are in `.module.ts` files, then the service is likely not injected anywhere.

Comment: The problem is that I would need to do that manually for every single service. That is what I want to avoid, there are tons of services.